# Positron-electron annihilation - can more than two photons be created?

Tags: particle-physics, photons

I'm an engineer and have been reading about PET scanners and how they rely on the fact that a positron-electron annihilation will cause two photons to be emitted at 180 degrees from each other. After a bit of research I am left wondering on a couple of points.

From [Electron–positron annihilation - wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation):

> Conservation of energy and linear momentum forbid the creation of only one photon.

Is this simply because emitting one photon would produce a force in one direction without an equal and opposite force?

> In the most common case, two photons are created, each with energy equal to the rest energy of the electron or positron.

Does it follow then that there is a (lesser) probability that 3 photons can be emitted at equal energy and equal angle of 120 degrees?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the requirement for at least two photons is because a single photon would violate conservation of momentum. See my answer to [Particle anti-particle annihilation and photon production](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215816/particle-anti-particle-annihilation-and-photon-production) for a (very simple!) proof of this.

Annihilation can produce more than two photons. In fact the decay of ortho-positronium to two photons is forbidden, and [it (mostly) decays into three photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71856/why-does-positronium-decay-into-2-photons-more-often-than-into-3-photons). This is a bit of a special case though as it's due to conservation of angular momentum in a bound state.

Answer (score 3):

The [LEP accelerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Electron%E2%80%93Positron_Collider) and the experiments running on it were e+e- annihilations, the energies on the Z resonance and also up to 210GeV . These annihilations had a [large variation in the particles detected](http://aleph.web.cern.ch/aleph/aleph/newpub/dali-displays.html) and a great number of decay channels published in numerous papers.